# Remove "label" in chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm using Chart.js v2.7.2 and want to remove the "label" field. Leaving it off returns "undefined" and the various options I've tried have done nothing. Anyone have new insight on this? Legend, title, etc all fail to remove it.

```
let thisChart = new Chart(gov_chart, {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        data: {
            label: 'I want to remove this',
            labels: [data1, data2],
            datasets: [{
                backgroundColor: ['rgb(240,61,74)', 'rgb(0, 156, 255)'],
                data: [data1.count, data2.count],
                }]
            },
        options: {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            },
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            title: {
                display: false
            },
            tooltips: {
                callbacks: {
                    label: function(tooltipItem) {
                        return tooltipItem.yLabel;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `label` should be inside `datasets` such as

```
type: 'horizontalBar',
data: {  
  labels: [data1, data2],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'put it here', // => here
    backgroundColor: ['rgb(240,61,74)', 'rgb(0, 156, 255)'],
    data: [data1.count, data2.count],
  }]
},
```

so you won't get undefined

**Updated:**
if you don't want to see it, put `legend` configuration inside the `options`. Apparently, I saw that your `legend` is outside `options` object.

```
options: {        
  legend: {
    display: false
  }
}
```

Comment: But I don't want to see it at all.

Comment: @Alicia I added about the legend to set it off :)

Comment: @Alicia no worries 

Answer (score 24):

Note, the accepted answer is outdated for 3.x.  To remove the legend you now have to specify the plugin.  https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html

eg

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: data,
   options: {
      plugins: {
         legend: {
            display: false
         }
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: The selected answer is still correct and relevant to [ChartJS 2.x](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/configuration/legend.html#configuration-options) while your link refers to [ChartJS 3.x](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html) or Latest. Offering a solution without noting the major version the configuration works can be confusing to some. I recommend noting the major supported version for your proposed solution to minimize further confusion from those seeking the correct answer depending on their ChartJS version.

Comment: Note that adding the plugins section to the options does not break ChartJS 2.x

Answer (score 1):

Update for V4:
If you want to remove x completely with labels, just add this to options:

```
options: {
    scales: {
        x: {
            display: false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter to remove out the label you don't want to show

```
options: {
   plugins: {
     legend: {
       labels: {
          filter: (l) => (l.text !== 'Label you want to remove')
       }
     }
   }
}
```